# Why is my custom error handler not called?

Tags: php, error-handling

When my script starts, I have:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

And then, I register my custom error handler with PHP:

```
function handleError($code, $text, $file, $line) {
    echo "&%!!";
    return true;
}

set_error_handler('handleError');
```

Next, there comes some code that produces an error like this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   DB::getInstanceForDB() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/classes/Test.php
>   on line 32

I keep getting the standard PHP error message box with call stack and everything on my site, no matter if I specify a custom error handler or not. Any idea what's wrong?

Edit: No matter if I return true or not, it doesn't call my custom handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to make your error handling function return true. From [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler):

> If the function returns FALSE then the normal error handler continues.

Second, be aware that fatal errors aren't handled by `set_error_handler`.  You need to use [register_shutdown_function](http://us.php.net/register_shutdown_function) as well.  So your code should look like this:

```
// Handles non-fatal errors
function handleError($code, $text, $file, $line) {
    var_dump($code);
    return true;
}
set_error_handler('handleError');

// Handles fatal errors
function fatalShutdown() {
    var_dump(error_get_last());
}
register_shutdown_function('fatalShutdown');
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is wrong because a shutdown function is called on all shutdowns, including those handled elsewhere, or just when a page finishes successfully.

I ended up with this, in addition to using set_exception_handler and set_error_handler:

```
// from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
define('FATAL', E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING);

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

// Handles "fatal" errors e.g. Syntax errors
function shutdown() {
    // Only if there was an fatal error, this is run on all execution endpoints
    $error_info = error_get_last();
    if ($error_info !== null && ($error_info['type'] & FATAL)) {
        # stack trace set to empty array, as generating one here is useless
        [[ do stuff like emailing someone]]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you're telling you are getting a Fatal Error.

I don't think you can catch those, as they are... well... Fatal.

Quoting [`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/set_error_handler) :

> The following error types cannot be
>   handled with a user defined function:
>   `E_ERROR`, `E_PARSE`, `E_CORE_ERROR`,
>   `E_CORE_WARNING`, `E_COMPILE_ERROR`,
>   `E_COMPILE_WARNING`, and most of
>   `E_STRICT` raised in the file where
>   `set_error_handler()` is called.